# Gmod Lua: making a simple SWEP with an overlay attached

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I am trying to make a swep where the user will have their overlay switched to models/shadertest/shader4 on weapon pick up, the gmod wiki says it is DrawMaterialOverlay( "string material", refract ) but its not working

Comment: share a [mcve]. as is your post cannot be answered. you did not ask a question btw.  please read [ask]. why don't you provide a link to the manual? what is "not working" supposed to mean? is there an error? what do you expect, what happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
DrawMaterialOverlay("models/shadertest/shader4", 0.5)
```

change the value of 0.5 to increase or decrease the effect.
in documentation, the function prototype gives you the nature and name of the arguments.
You're meant to replace each argument with what **you** want to use.

Here, first is expected a *string* that represents the *name of the material*. You know that one
Second argument expects a *number* that represents the *amount of refraction*. You don't know how much looks good, so try different values